# Wildfly - Change Management Realm's Password

Tags: wildfly

Is there any way of changing Wildfly's Management Realm's password through config files of some sort? I kinda lost my password (my LastPass add-on for Firefox is kinda messing up with me). If there is, how?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Passwords by default are stored in

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties
```

but passwords are hashed.
Best thing you can do is to remove the user you want and then re-add it via add-user.sh/.bat script you can find in bin folder.

Comment: I discovered that (and forgot to update my question here), so yeah I removed the user and re-add one. Thank you for answering!

Comment: do you know how can i retrieve the username and password in java from the application-user.properties?

Answer (score 24):

If you are using WildFly the add-user utility has the ability to replace existing passwords, just run it again for a user with the same username and it should give you the option to replace the password.